# How to center 2 <div> in a <div>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem. I have a full width row with some css style on it, and in this row I have 2 different column size as you can see in my code.

What I need to do is that the **col-xs-12 col-lg-3** & **col-xs-12 col-lg-9** is to be in a container of the website, something like 1220px width. First column is a vertical menu with 20% width, and the second one is a slider with 80% width.

How could I center this in this case. Thanks for your answers.

```
<div class="different-row-class">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would place it in a `container`, confused as to what you're trying to centre.

Comment: So what does *center* mean? So that they fill out 100% perfectly? Or that they meet at 50%?

Comment: Look how it is right now. https://imgur.com/a/FsXE4 .

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I want the "different-row-class" to fill 100% perfectly, and the last 2 divs to be in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question looks ambiguous, maybe this could help you out:

If you want the different-row-class to fill 100% width, use "container-fluid".
End the container  you started above.

Then:

```
<div class="container-fluid different-row-class">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can avoid nested containers anytime though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9"></div>
</div>
```

put your div into a container

Comment: Can't add in a container cuz' it is already in one. As you can see here https://imgur.com/a/FsXE4, I need the "Produse" section from left to be aligned with the logo, and the navbar to be aligned between search bar and shopping cart

Comment: Sorry I don't konw how to add the code, I know to add here just as inline. Look here https://imgur.com/a/qGre6

Comment: edit your question.just copy paste your html code here.

Comment: Look here

<div class="row">
 <div class="header-logo"></div>
  <form class="navbar-search" method="get" action="link"></form>
  <ul class="navbar-mini-cart..."></ul>
  <ul class="navbar-wishlit...."</ul>
  <ul class="navbar-compare...."</ul>
 </div>
 <div class="different-row-class"></div>
  <div class="col-sx-12 col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9"></div>
 </div>
</div>